# Parse a PDF document with ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, pdf, scripting, ocr

I have multiple PDF documents in a folder that have a certain structure:

[image]

Now I want to be able to parse the information from the PDF. Please note that the paragraphs have varying lengths.

Obviously I am not asking you to solve the problem for me, but I do need some pointers as to how this can be achieved.

I have used nokogiri before and technically I need something like that but for PDFs.

So the pseudo result for my example would look like this:

```
- ItemA
  - Title: ItemA
  - File: 123456789.pdf
  - Image: ImageA.png (the image was stored on disk)
  - Subtitle1: Content for subtitle 1
  - Subtitle2: Content for subtitle 2
  - Subtitle3: Content for subtitle 3
- TitleB
  - [...]
```

Comment: Although you have worded this carefully, I think you may be better off just going direct for a software recommendation question on the beta site http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ - there are a few PDF manipulation libraries out there, and it looks like you want something that will parse nicely into a data structure. Asking for "best Ruby library to parse PDFs" and using the content from your question here would I think be a very acceptable question on that SE site. Chances are the library will include example code.

Comment: @NeilSlater Hey Neill, thanks for your comment. I am aware that the style of my question is a bit tricky. I do think though that it is a specific software software engineering problem and I did post my own answer already, so that other folks can still benefit.

Comment: OK, I don't think it is off-topic, just that you might get a different focus (best tool for the job) answers on the other site. If you are going to self-answer, then I think it will be very useful for others to find this on SO. The best link under "Related" is clearly out of date and nowadays would be considered off topic

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`pdf-reader` is one of the solution. But it has issues sometimes it doesn't give text in proper format. I have used it.

I will suggest to use **[docsplit](https://github.com/documentcloud/docsplit)** . You will find more information about 'pdf-reader' and 'docsplit' in **[this blog post](http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2014/08/13/pdf-to-plain-text-processing-using-docsplit/)**.

Hope this helps. In case any clarification is required, feel free to comment.

Comment: im using pdf-reader now.  just came across an issue where it doesn't do a great job handling superscripts.  ie. if there is 50 superscript 100, it will read it as "50100"

Comment: yeah, docsplit didnt help.  i got it to work, after much effort.  pdf-reader has this callback function where you can access every little piece of data in the PDF before their library processes it.  so i used callbacks and parsed it myself, then combined it with the other data from pdf-reader that wasn't corrupted

Answer (score 7):

## Getting the text

The text can easily be parsed like so:

```
# gem install pdf-reader
require 'pdf-reader'

reader = PDF::Reader.new('my.pdf')

reader.pages.each do |page|
  puts page.text
end
```

## Saving the image

This can be done with the same library. See the example script [examples/extract_images.rb](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader/blob/master/examples/extract_images.rb).

## However

This is (not yet) a complete answer. 
The next steps would now be to:

1. Parse the text and look for the headings
2. Crop the image, which can be achieved with a library like RMagick or [Mini Magick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick).